# How to add web modules on Tomcat server in eclipse using plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a eclipse plugin that setups a tomcat server and configure it. I managed to create the server like this :

```
// Create a new server object
IServerType tomcatServerType = null;

for (IServerType serverType : ServerCore.getServerTypes())
{
   if (serverType.getId().equals("org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.60"))
   {
      tomcatServerType = serverType;
   }
}

IRuntimeWorkingCopy runtimeCopy = tomcatServerType.getRuntimeType().createRuntime("Apache tomcat v6.0", monitor);
      runtimeCopy.setLocation(new Path(tomcatPath));
      runtimeCopy.save(true, monitor);

IServerWorkingCopy server = tomcatServerType.createServer("My tomcat server", null, monitor);
```

The next step to configure the  server is to get from eclipse all imported projects that can be used to configure a server, i do so like this :

```
IProject[] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
for (IProject project : projects)
{
   // Check if the project is a web project
   if (project.hasNature("org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature"))
   {
      if (project.getName().contains(resourceName))
      {
         @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
         WebModule webModule = new WebModule(project.getName(), project.getName(), project.getName(), true);
         IModule[] modules = new IModule[]
         { (IModule) webModule };
         server.modifyModules(modules, null, monitor);
      }
   }
}
```

Here is my problem : using `project.hasNature()` I can check if a project can be used to configure the server and I even managed to create a WebModule from it but then there is no way to convert it to a IModule to add it to the server. How do I add the found project to the server as resource ?